# How to implement a login page in a GWT app?

Tags: gwt, authentication, rpc

My WebApp needs to authenticate user before allowing any sort of access. The scenario I'm trying to implement is a login page with username and password fields. Once user hits "send" button, a sign like "Verifing..." should be shown up while an RPC call verifies credentials. In case of success, load the main app screen.

What is the best way to implement that?

Comment: What exactly is not clear to you?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you looked at [this page](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ) ?

It describes how to do the following:

- Create a 'login' page that is based
  on user/password authentication.
- Store this data in a secure fashion
  on your server.
- Allow users to 'remain logged in' for
  as long as you want so they don't
  have to enter their user name and
  password every time.
- Make 'auto-complete' features of most
  modern browsers work with your GWT's
  login page. Discussion on adding more
  security with either HTTPS or fancy
  hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how well secure your application has to be... but I would suggest leaving that piece of work to spring security.

You could make a regular login.html page which would, upon successful login, redirect user to the "real" gwt app.

Check out this article:
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/security_for_gwt_applications.html

Answer (score 0):

Not tailored directly for GWT (can still integrate with it), this is a great tutorial for implementing a secure login system.

http://drdobbs.com/web-development/231002659